# Превращения строки в число с плавающей точкой

Tags: c++

Нужно перевести строку, которая имеет цифры и точку, в число. Подобной вопрос видел на форуме, но там было переведения строки в целочисленное значение, а для работы с числом с плавающей точкой он не подходит. Нужно значения с переменной S передать в переменную n.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    string S = "74.4";
    float n;
    /*магический код, где переводится строка в число*/
    cout << n;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [std::stof](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)

Comment: [strtof](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod), [sscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf)

Comment: Вам нужна функция стандартной библиотеки или написать собственную?

Comment: желательно стандартную, но человек сверху уже ответил)